# Using WSO2products in my organization.Is it chargeable?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

i run an organization in which i have some applications specifically for my employees.For managing these apps i have found WSO2 products quite useful, i have gone through their documentation in which WSO2 appm and wso2 EMM were seems to be useful.I want to ask that is these products are free of cost or i have to pay for it and do some licensing in order to use it.And please tell me that is wso2 provides some support in case any bugs occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the [WSO2 products](http://wso2.com/products/) are free and open source  and based on Open Standards. Developers can extend the platform, customize code and use any programming model they like.

You can use it without paying any thing.

But, You have to pay for any further [support](http://wso2.com/support/).

> Our financial business model is based upon providing the best support
>   in the industry. From project evaluation and inception to development
>   and going into production, we strive for a support experience that
>   customers value and renew.

Regarding MDM of [WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/), It's said [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Architecture)

> The Mobile Device Management (MDM) module enables the administrator to
>   manage the devices that are registered with EMM. WSO2 EMM is designed
>   to have a plugin architecture giving it the ability to implement new
>   device platforms and plug them easily. As a result, WSO2 EMM has the
>   Android, iOS and Windows platforms plugged into the MDM core.

Comment: if i need some support then do i have to pay , or the support available is free.And one more thing, does wso2 provides any mdm.

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply, and can we configure any mdm with wso2. Can u plz elaborate about mdm usage with wso2 appm/emm

Comment: Is updating the apps through appm/emm possible after the app gets published.And can we force the user to download the updated app by giving some sort of notification

Comment: Updating the app through emm/appm is possible!